# In Visual Studio 2013 Gid App, how can you use a combo box to change the json file?

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-2013

I am struggling with this, as my programming knowledge is very limited.

I am using c++ in Visual Studio and I was creating an app using the Grid App Template, and I want to be able to use multiple json files to draw the necessary data from. In SampleDataSource.cpp, I used the ComboBoxSelectionChanged function to build an if statement saying if a specific index is selected, change the json file to the necessary json.

This is so I can allow the user to look at whatever set of data they select with the combo box. So far everything executes properly, but when the program runs, the data is the same regardless of selection. I'm not sure if it needs to be redrawn or updated, but I'm at a loss after researching this for days.

I appreciate the help ahead of time.

Edit: I'm attempting to post the code.

I apologize for being unable to get the first part of the code to show up correctly, but the most important part that I've been editing is about halfway down.

`

SampleDataItem::SampleDataItem(String^ uniqueId, String^ title, String^ subtitle, String^ imagePath, String^ description,
    String^ content) :
    _uniqueId(uniqueId),
    _title(title),
    _subtitle(subtitle),
    _description(description),
    _imagePath(imagePath),
    _content(content)
    {
    }

```
String^ SampleDataItem::UniqueId::get()
{
    return _uniqueId;
}

String^ SampleDataItem::Title::get()
{
    return _title;
}

String^ SampleDataItem::Subtitle::get()
{
    return _subtitle;
}

String^ SampleDataItem::Description::get()
{
    return _description;
}

String^ SampleDataItem::Content::get()
{
    return _content;
}

String^ SampleDataItem::ImagePath::get()
{
    return _imagePath;
}

Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::ICustomProperty^ SampleDataItem::GetCustomProperty(Platform::String^ name)
{
    return nullptr;
}

Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::ICustomProperty^ SampleDataItem::GetIndexedProperty(Platform::String^ name, Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName type)
{
    return nullptr;
}

Platform::String^ SampleDataItem::GetStringRepresentation()
{
    return Title;
}

Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName SampleDataItem::Type::get()
{
    return this->GetType();
}

//
// SampleDataGroup
//

SampleDataGroup::SampleDataGroup(String^ uniqueId, String^ title, String^ subtitle, String^ imagePath, String^ description) :
    _uniqueId(uniqueId),
    _title(title),
    _subtitle(subtitle),
    _description(description),
    _imagePath(imagePath),
    _items(ref new Vector<SampleDataItem^>())
    {
    }

    String^ SampleDataGroup::UniqueId::get()
    {
        return _uniqueId;
    }

    String^ SampleDataGroup::Title::get()
    {
        return _title;
    }

    String^ SampleDataGroup::Subtitle::get()
    {
        return _subtitle;
    }

    String^ SampleDataGroup::Description::get()
    {
        return _description;
    }

    IObservableVector<SampleDataItem^>^ SampleDataGroup::Items::get()
    {
        return _items;
    }

    String^ SampleDataGroup::ImagePath::get()
    {
        return _imagePath;
    }

    Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::ICustomProperty^ SampleDataGroup::GetCustomProperty(Platform::String^ name)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::ICustomProperty^ SampleDataGroup::GetIndexedProperty(Platform::String^ name, Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName type)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    Platform::String^ SampleDataGroup::GetStringRepresentation()
    {
        return Title;
    }

    Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop::TypeName SampleDataGroup::Type::get()
    {
        return this->GetType();
    }

    //
    // SampleDataSource
    //
    String^ address = "ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleData1900.json";

    void Flag_Project::GroupedItemsPage::ComboBox_SelectionChanged(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::SelectionChangedEventArgs^ e)
    {

        int selectedIndex = combobox1->SelectedIndex;
        Object^ selectedItem = combobox1->SelectedItem;

        if (selectedIndex = 1)
        {
            address = "ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleData.json";


            this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(GroupedItemsPage::typeid));
        }

    }

    SampleDataSource::SampleDataSource()
    {
        _groups = ref new Vector<SampleDataGroup^>();

        Uri^ uri = ref new Uri(address);
        create_task(StorageFile::GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri))
            .then([](StorageFile^ storageFile)
        {
            return FileIO::ReadTextAsync(storageFile);
        })
            .then([this](String^ jsonText)
        {
            JsonObject^ jsonObject = JsonObject::Parse(jsonText);
            auto jsonVector = jsonObject->GetNamedArray("Groups")->GetView();

            for (const auto &jsonGroupValue : jsonVector)
            {
                JsonObject^ groupObject = jsonGroupValue->GetObject();
                SampleDataGroup^ group = ref new SampleDataGroup(groupObject->GetNamedString("UniqueId"),
                    groupObject->GetNamedString("Title"),
                    groupObject->GetNamedString("Subtitle"),
                    groupObject->GetNamedString("ImagePath"),
                    groupObject->GetNamedString("Description"));

                auto jsonItemVector = groupObject->GetNamedArray("Items")->GetView();
                for (const auto &jsonItemValue : jsonItemVector)
                {
                    JsonObject^ itemObject = jsonItemValue->GetObject();

                    SampleDataItem^ item = ref new SampleDataItem(itemObject->GetNamedString("UniqueId"),
                        itemObject->GetNamedString("Title"),
                        itemObject->GetNamedString("Subtitle"),
                        itemObject->GetNamedString("ImagePath"),
                        itemObject->GetNamedString("Description"),
                        itemObject->GetNamedString("Content"));

                    group->Items->Append(item);
                };

                _groups->Append(group);
            };
        })
            .then([this](task<void> t)
        {
            try
            {
                t.get();
            }
            catch (Platform::COMException^ e)
            {
                OutputDebugString(e->Message->Data());
                // TODO: If App can recover from exception,
                // remove throw; below and add recovery code.
                throw;
            }
            // Signal load completion event
            _loadCompletionEvent.set();
        });
    }

    IObservableVector<SampleDataGroup^>^ SampleDataSource::Groups::get()
    {
        return _groups;
    }

    SampleDataSource^ SampleDataSource::_sampleDataSource = nullptr;

    task<void> SampleDataSource::Init()
    {
        if (_sampleDataSource == nullptr)
        {
            _sampleDataSource = ref new SampleDataSource();
        }
        return create_task(_sampleDataSource->_loadCompletionEvent);
    }

    task<IIterable<SampleDataGroup^>^> SampleDataSource::GetGroups()
    {
        return Init()
            .then([]() -> IIterable<SampleDataGroup^> ^
        {
            return _sampleDataSource->Groups;
        });
    }

    task<SampleDataGroup^> SampleDataSource::GetGroup(String^ uniqueId)
    {
        return Init()
            .then([uniqueId]() -> SampleDataGroup ^
        {
            // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
            for (const auto& group : _sampleDataSource->Groups)
            {
                if (group->UniqueId == uniqueId)
                {
                    return group;
                }
            }
            return nullptr;
        });
    }

    task<SampleDataItem^> SampleDataSource::GetItem(String^ uniqueId)
    {
        return Init()
            .then([uniqueId]() -> SampleDataItem ^
        {
            // Simple linear search is acceptable for small data sets
            for (const auto& group : _sampleDataSource->Groups)
            {
                for (const auto& item : group->Items)
                {
                    if (item->UniqueId == uniqueId)
                    {
                        return item;
                    }
                }
            }
            return nullptr;
        });
    }`
```

Comment: This smells like C++/CLI, not Standard C++.

Comment: A description of the code is not helpful without actually posting the code you've tried.

Comment: Sorry, I have added the code for that particular file.